# Write a large Inputstream to File in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a large stream of text coming back from REST web service and I would like to write it directly to file. What is the simplest way of doing this?

I have written the following function extension that WORKS. But I can't help thinking that there is a cleaner way of doing this.

**Note**: I was hoping to use try with resources to auto close the stream and file

```
fun File.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream) {
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)

    inputStream.use { input ->
        this.outputStream().use { fileOut ->

            while (true) {
                val length = input.read(buffer)
                if (length <= 0)
                    break
                fileOut.write(buffer, 0, length)
            }
            fileOut.flush()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can simplify your function by using the [copyTo function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/copy-to.html):

```
fun File.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream) {
    this.outputStream().use { fileOut ->
        inputStream.copyTo(fileOut)
    }
}
```

Comment: The outer `use` seems like a mistake. You are closing/disposing in a different scope than the one in which `inputStream` was opened.

Comment: And to do the opposite (write from file to some outputStream), I use this: `FileInputStream(someFile).use { stream -> stream.copyTo(someOutputStream) }` , right?

Comment: Andre's comment is no longer relevant as the answer has been edited

Answer (score 17):

My proposition is:

```
fun InputStream.toFile(path: String) {
    File(path).outputStream().use { this.copyTo(it) }
}
```

without closing current stream

```
InputStream.toFile("/path/filename")
```

also, do not forget to handle exceptions, for example if write permission is denied :)

Answer (score 10):

I suggest to make like this:

```
fun InputStream.toFile(path: String) {
    use { input ->
        File(path).outputStream().use { input.copyTo(it) }
    }
}
```

and then to use like:

```
InputStream.toFile("/some_path_to_file")
```

Comment: You should always close in the same scope you opened in. This is likely the reason `copyTo` doesn't automatically close the resources for you.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to do like this

```
@Throws
fun copyDataBase() {

        var myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME)
        var outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME
        var fileOut: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(outFileName)
        val buffer: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024)
        var length: Int? = 0

        while (true) {
            length = myInput.read(buffer)
            if (length <= 0)
                break
            fileOut.write(buffer, 0, length)
        }

        fileOut.flush()
        fileOut.close()
        myInput.close()

        throw IOException()
}
```

Comment: That buffer size may be a bit too small. Usually something between 8192 and 32768 bytes is used. For example, Kotlin's own InputStream#copyTo uses 8192 B as a default default and Go's copy uses 32768 (there it cannot be changed). Source: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/copy-to.html Source: https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=11569:11629#L389

Comment: Is not necessary call .flush() and then close()

Answer (score -1):

What appears to have worked for me is this:

```
fun fileCopyer(localFileA: File, localFileB: File) {
var output = localFileA.inputStream()
output.copyTo(localFileB.outputStream())
output.close()
}
```